# How to not get out of a condition once you get into it?

Tags: python, algorithm

Imagine I have something like this.
x is computed every second and has different value every second. Based on the value of x, I want to do something different to x

```
if 10 > x > 0:
   print "It's temporary"
   do_something(x)
elif x < 0:
   print "It gets activated but stay activated"
   do_something_else(x)
```

if x has the first condition, it doesn't get into condition two, but what I'm interested is that once x went to the second condition, even if x gets back and becomes positive, it doesn't get into the first condition, but stays in the second condition.

Is there any stereotypic algorithm to do such a thing?

Comment: What do you mean _even if x gets back and becomes positive_? Are you recursing?

Comment: x is computed every second and has different value every second. Based on the value of x, I want to do something different to x.

Comment: Let me rephrase what I think you're asking - you want to evaluate x on a number of iterations, then as soon as x does not meet your first condition you want to continually execute what is in your `elif` statement regardless of the future values of x?

Comment: Yes @DonkeyKong That's true.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but would a boolean work? `activitated = False`, then set it to `True` in the `elif` and check it in the `if`?

Comment: What changes the value of `x`?

Comment: @chepner What do you mean? another function in another script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarifications in comments, it appears the following recursive function could be adapted for your purpose

```
def do_something(x, stayActivated = False):
    if not stayActivated and (10 > x > 0):
        print "It's temporary"
        # make an adjustment with said external function
        do_something(x)
    elif not stayActivated and x < 0:
        print "It gets activated but stays activated"
        do_something_else(x, stayActivated = True)
    elif x < 0:
        # x has already been activated and other handling can be applied until any final 
        # condition is met
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work, assuming you can adapt it to the environment where `x` is not a static value.

```
while 10 > x > 0:
    print "It's temporary"
    do_something(x)
while True:  # or something that has a chance of being false
    if x < 0:
        print "It gets activated but stay activated"
        do_something_else(x)
```